# How regex works in Ruta?

Tags: regex, uima, ruta

I am trying to validate date and other expressions using regex. It works in java but fail to annotate in RUTA.

Sample input :

```
Date 10-20-1994
```

Code :

```
// Field Name - Date (Regex)
DECLARE Keyword DateKeyword;
DECLARE Entity Date;
"Date" -> DateKeyword("label"="Date");
BLOCK(feature13) Line{CONTAINS(DateKeyword)} {
 DateKeyword c:ANY+{REGEXP("^\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}$")->CREATE(Date, "label"= "Date", "value"=c.ct)};
}
```

Fails to annotate date. Please suggest what I have missed.

For alphanumeric string

input - `test_2309`    annotates `test`

input - `test2309`     annotates `test2309`

code - `c:ANY+{REGEXP("[a-zA-Z0-9]*")`

How to make sure it annotates all or returns false. Instead of returning covered text?

Comment: Date works using following `c:#{REGEXP("^\\d{2}\\-\\d{2}\\-\\d{4}$")->CREATE(Date)`

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression patterns work the same way they do in Java. What you miss is the annotation span on which the regex should be applied. In your original case `ANY+` matches on each token iteratively (not as a whole as you would expect). Therefore "10", "-", "20" and so on do not satifsy the regex pattern. You should first create an annotation on the desired span and apply the regex on it.

```
DECLARE DateKeyword (STRING label);
DECLARE Date (STRING label, STRING value);
DECLARE DateCandidate, Dash;

SPECIAL{-PARTOF(Dash), REGEXP("[-]")-> Dash};

"Date" -> DateKeyword("label"="Date");
DateKeyword ANY[1,5]{OR(PARTOF(Dash), PARTOF(NUM)), -PARTOF(W) -> DateCandidate};
BLOCK(feature13) Line{CONTAINS(DateKeyword)} {
    DateKeyword c:DateCandidate{REGEXP("\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}")->CREATE(Date, "label"= "Date", "value"=c.ct)};
}
```

Alternatively, you could just apply the regex pattern on separate Ruta seed annotations:

```
(NUM{REGEXP("\\d{2}")} SPECIAL NUM{REGEXP("\\d{2}")} SPECIAL NUM{REGEXP("\\d{4}")}){-PARTOF(Date) -> Date};
```